# Magento if statement not working on live but works on localhost

Tags: php, magento

I have the exact same code on my localhost as I do on the live server but it only works on localhost.

```
<?php if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) : echo "<div id='newsletter_sign_up' style='display:none;' >

<div style='padding:20px;' >
<form action=".$this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new')." method='post' >
  <div class='fieldset'>
    <!--update on Sep16, for merge Tim work for newsleeter
    //start
    //<h2 class='legend'>Newsletter Sign-up</h2>
    -->
    <h1 style='color: #28ced7; text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 28px;'>Science and Beauty News + Special Promotions!</h1>

    <h2 class='legend' style='text-align:left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;'>Sign up for our e-Newsletters and take advantage of special offers, promotions, contests and other exciting news. We average just two emails a month and you can opt out at any time. We respect and protect the privacy of our customers and those who use our website.</h2>
    <!--end-->
    <ul class='form-list'>
      <li class='fields'>
        <div class='customer-name'><div class='field name-firstname'>
            <label class='required' for='firstname' style='text-align:left;'><em>*</em>First Name</label>
            <div class='input-box'>
              <input type='text' class='input-text required-entry' maxlength='255' title='First Name' value='' name='firstname' id='firstname' autocomplete='off'/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='field name-lastname'>
            <label class='required' for='lastname' style='text-align:left;'><em>*</em>Last Name</label>
            <div class='input-box'>
              <input type='text' class='input-text required-entry' maxlength='255' title='Last Name' value='' name='lastname' id='lastname' autocomplete='off'/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class='required' for='email_address'  style='text-align:left;'><em>*</em>Email Address</label>
        <div class='input-box'>

          <input type='text' class='input-text validate-email required-entry' title='Email Address' value='' id='email_address' name='email' autocomplete='off'/>

      <input class='pop_newsletter_source' name='source' type='hidden' value='3' />

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='buttons-set form-buttons'>
    <button onclick='pop_newsletter.submit(); return false;' title='Submit' class='button' type='submit' autocomplete='off' style='position: relative; right: 140px;'><span><span>Submit</span></span></button>
  </div>
  <p class='required'>* Required Fields</p>
  <!--//merge Tim work for newsletter-->
  <h2 style='text-align: left; font-size: 10px;'>Email Privacy Statement:</h2>
  <p style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; text-align: left;'>We will not share, sell, rent, swap or authorize any third party to use your e-mail address. If you no longer wish to receive e-news, follow the 'unsubscribe' instructions located near the bottom of each newsletter</p>
  <!--//end-->
</form>"; ?>


</div></div>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

When i `print_r`

```
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()); echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

it gives me a '1'.

Additionally I've tried:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getPageId() == '2' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
```

When I `print_r` it tells me my pageid is 2. I'm so confused. Honestly I don't have much more information or code to give or expand on.

Answer (score 0):

Rad
Try this

```
<?php if(
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  &&
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' 
) : ? >

//insert your code here 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Here home is  your home page url for check goto Admin>CMS>pages> Select your home page and here URL Key is identifier

Comment: Still not working correctly, any other ideas or configuration that might be bad?

Comment: It's still firing on all pages when i only want it to popup on the home page.